# css overlapping and not doing want i want it to do

Tags: html, css, padding, overlapping

I have this css

```
#navlinks{
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /*padding-right:50px;*/
    padding-top:2px;
    text-indent:40px;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    padding-left:100;
    /*float:leff;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:nowrap;


}
```

that i put on this header

```
#header{
    background-image:url(../images/main_images/bar.png);
    padding: 0px;
    top:0;
    /*background-color: #666666;*/
    height: 131px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    /*border-left: 1px solid #000000;*/
    /*border-right: 1px solid #000000;*/
    /*border-bottom: 0 solid #000000;*/
    /*border-top: 5px;*/
     /*solid #000000;*/

    /*border-width: 5px;*/
    width: 1030px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*border-radius: 5px;*/
    position:fixed;

}
```

the problem is i get this result

image [image]

what i want it to do is be spaced out about 20 pixels from each other so i used padding what happened then was border were overlapping each other so clicking on home would click help and not home

side question: on my header you notice how i havea  margin: 0 auto; that is suppose to make it float center and it worked tell i made the position fixed how do i fix that?

note: if you goto worthsomethinggaming.com i made that site legit 1 week after i learned html (and a little css) dont make fun of me lol

Comment: can you please post a fiddle..

Comment: "is the on being clicked(active link css)" um what? it whuld click help and not home*

Comment: Posting a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#run) would be really helpfull..

Comment: What do you mean a fiddle? i don't use a lot of css this is one of the first projects i have really used it in

Comment: İts better to add a fiddle

Comment: you just go to the link that i said in my earlier comment and just paste the html,css and js codes and click update and share that link with us..

Comment: post your html codes :/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the length Value in `padding-left:100;`add px to it.

Like this  `padding-left:100px;`